# Check my work for motion problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

This is the problem I am trying to solve:

> An employee drove to work on Monday at $45$mi/h and arrived one minute early. The employee drove to work on Tuesday, leaving home at the same time driving $40$m/h and arriving one minute late.
>
> **a.** How far does the employee live from work?
>
> **b.** At what speed should the employee drive to arrive five minutes early?

My work:
$$45(x-1)=40(x+1)$$
$$45x-45=40x+40$$
$$5x=85$$
$$x=17$$
Now it starts to get a little shady. I think this is the time it will take the employee to arrive on time, so I substituted it into the equation $d=rt$ with $r$ being $45$ and $t$ being $16$. This gave me the result of $720$, which seems unreasonable for the distance.

Am I doing anything wrong? If so, please explain.

> **Note:** Please do not offer the solution; I want to solve this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing units. The speeds are in miles per *hour*, but the time difference is in *minutes*.

As @thunderbolt's comment indicates, yes, you can fix this by dividing the final answer by $60$ to give $12$ miles, which is the correct answer for part a). But I think the working has to be clearer.

(The reason why this works here is the factor of $\frac{1}{60}$ on both sides cancels out, so the equation still holds. However, I would start by writing the equation properly to begin with, otherwise it looks like the student is not aware of the different units of time involved here.)

Comment: Can I fix that just by dividing 720 by 60?

Comment: Use (x-1/60) and (x+1/60) and work it out again.

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? Was there something wrong?

Comment: @thunderbolt I realised I hadn't been clear enough with just the first line. While the difference of units is an issue, the equation itself is true (because of the cancellation, as I mentioned). So I edited. While you can "fix" your error by dividing by 60 at the last step, I prefer working that keeps the units consistent.

Comment: I see. Can you check what I wrote on @copper.hat's answer?

Comment: I am still stuck, any help?

Comment: @thunderbolt Which part are you stuck on? I can edit my answer to give a complete solution, but is that what you want?

Comment: @Deepak I got it after a while, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use more meaningful symbols and write down the data first:

${d \over 45} = T-{1 \over 60}$

${d \over 40} = T+{1 \over 60}$.

From this you can compute $d$.

From this you can compute $T$.

Now compute $v$ such that

${d \over v} = T-{5 \over 60}$.

Answers:

> $d=12$, $T = {17 \over 60}$, $v=60$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was just staring at this answer...

Comment: I am computing that right now. I got 4/15 for d and 1201/60 for t, which i fear is incorrect

Comment: I am still stuck, any help?

Comment: Check your computations. I added the answers, but this is just a case of grinding through the numbers.

Comment: I'm just so tired, I can hardly stay awake. I'll just recheck this tomorrow.

Comment: by the way, can you help on my [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967925/check-my-work-for-motion-problem-2?noredirect=1#comment4039406_1967925)?

Comment: Sorry, gotta hit the sack shortly.

Comment: Same, but I need to finish...I need to be up in about 6 hours